# Terraform openstack instance doesn't return floating ip

Tags: terraform, openstack, floating-ip

Im setting up and openstack instance using terraform. Im writing to a file the ip returned but for some reason its alwayse empty (i have looked at the instance in openstack consol and everythign is correct with ip, securitygroups etc etc)

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "my-deployment-web" {
  count = "1"
  name = "my-name-WEB"
  flavor_name = "m1.medium"
  image_name = "RHEL7Secretname"
  security_groups = [
    "our_security_group"]
  key_pair = "our-keypair"   


  network {
    name = "public"
  }

  metadata {
    expire = "2",
    owner = ""
  }

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "vagrant"
    private_key = "config/vagrant_private.key"
    agent = "false"
    timeout = "15m"
  }

  ##Create Ansible host in staging inventory
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  "echo -e '\n[web]\n${openstack_compute_instance_v2.my-deployment-web.network.0.floating_ip}' > ../ansible/inventories/staging/hosts"
    interpreter = ["sh", "-c"]
  }    
}
```

The host file generated only gets [web] but no ip. Anyone know why?

```
[web]
```

Comment: Take a look at using a template instead of raw shell comands in a `local-exec`. That would be much easier for you: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html

Comment: I have that as well but the same problem that the variable doesn't resolve to the ip

Comment: Oh well then i guess that simplifies things. If I look at the documentation https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/r/compute_instance_v2.html#attributes-referencears the floating ip is not an attribute, which would explain it being empty. There are fixed ip attributes though.

Comment: you are correct. I picked it up from an example but its not valid as you said. For me it worked with '.access_ip_v4' instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the variable from

```
${openstack_compute_instance_v2.my-deployment-web.network.0.floating_ip}
```

to

`${openstack_compute_instance_v2.my-deployment-web.network.0.access_ip_v4`}

solved the problem. Thank you @Matt Schuchard